# Does silent push notification able to awake app which is in not running state in ios?

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, silentpush

i want to insert push notification data into sqlite even if my app is in not running state(Close state).
How do i achieve this???

- Type of Notification is silent push notification.

Comment: please put your code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Check out Apple's documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)

> If your server sends push notifications to a user’s device when new
>   content is available for your app, you can ask the system to run your
>   app in the background so that it can begin downloading the new content
>   right away.

Answer (score 1):

If the app has killed by a user or it's terminated by OS then your app will not awake.

Check this link [iOS Silent Push Notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937616/will-ios-awake-my-app-when-i-receive-silent-push-notificationwhen-app-is-not-i)